# Computing the tangent plane of a surface defined by a system of non linear equations

Tags: taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, implicit-function-theorem, linear-approximation

Consider a system 
$$
\sum_{0\le i,j\le N} x^i y^j A_{ij}(u,v) = 0 \qquad (*)
$$
where $x,y,u,v\in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_{ij}$ are $3\times 3$ matrices, whose entries are smooth functions of wrt $(u,v)$.

Let $(u^*(x,y),v^*(x,y))$ be a solution of $(*)$, that may be hard to compute explicitly.

Is it possible to compute a Taylor expansion of $(u^*(x,y),v^*(x,y))$ at the point $(0,0)$ up to order $N$ wrt $x,y$ ?

---

Consider the case $N=1$, so that the approximation we would like to compute is a plane.
Rewrite $(*)$ as $F(x,y,u,v)=0$. Applying the IFT, we can find a neighborhood $N$ of $0$ and a function $g$ such that 
$F(x,y,g(x,y))=0$ in $N$ and
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(0,0) = -Jac(F)_{xy}(x,y,0,0)^{-1}\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(x,y,0,0) \qquad (1)
\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(0,0) = -Jac(F)_{xy}(x,y,0,0)^{-1}\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(x,y,0,0)\qquad (2)
$$
and then the approximation would be given by
$$
(u^*,v^*)^\intercal = g(0,0) + u \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(0,0)
+ v \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(0,0) + o(u,v)
$$

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrices $A_{i,j}$? Also you mention $x,y,u,v \in \mathbb R$, but also denote $x^i y^j$ which seems not coherent. And the matrices are functions of $u,v$ ? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I edited the question. Why $x^i,y^j$ seem not coherent ?

Comment: What is strange is that if I understand well for $x,y$ given, you have $9$  real equations ($3 \times 3$ matrices) and only two unknowns $u,v$.

Comment: yes, I assume the existence of a solution